# Monitor blinks on and off and sometimes shuts off

Tags: dell, lenovo, thinkpad, displayport

I love Ubuntu and haven't even had to ask a question here but it seems the time has come that I must.  The newest version, 13.04, has a lot of problems.. but this problem is one that isn't specific 13.04 because I have tried 12.04 and 12.10 with the same results!

I have been using this Lenovo T520 with Intel Integrated Graphics 3000 and loving it.

A recently purchased Dell 27" Ultra-sharp U2713HM monitor with promised 2560x1440 resolution poses a problem.  Randomly during normal use (and almost instantly during heavy use) the monitor blinks off/on and sometimes shuts off completely forcing a manual restart of the monitor!

At lower resolution (1920x1200) over DisplayPort there are no problems at all.

In Windows 7, everything appears to be working perfectly as well.

I've installed the new May 20th 2013 Intel Integrated Graphics driver and the problem still persists.

Let me know if any information is needed but I would sure appreciate anyone that can take a minute to point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Also, when I disable the screen on my laptop the Dell U2713HM works great.  Is the Intel 3000 not powerful enough to power both?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but not only with Ubuntu. The same exists for Fedora 17-19, so it's linux specific in general. The machine in my case is a T420s with Intel Integrated Graphics 3000, and the second display in my case is a Dell 2407WFP on DVI. The symptoms are exactly the same as yours. As an additional note: if I unplug the displayport cord and plug it in again, everything works again, it seems something is putting the displayport link in powersave mode for a short period of time.